# Dart define generic function

Tags: dart

I used the following code to define a function type

```dart
typedef DownloadCallback = Future<StreamedResponse> Function<T>(
  BuildContext context,
  T fileIdentifier,
);
```

And created a function that is similar to the type

```dart
Future<StreamedResponse> publicFileDownloader(
  BuildContext context,
  String url,
) {
  final request = Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
  return Client().send(request);
}
```

But I have the following error

> The argument type 'Future Function(BuildContext, String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function(BuildContext, T)'.

How can I fix the error without using `dynamic` type?

Comment: Can you give a complete example showing the problem? (e.g. how you are using the `publicFileDownloader` method and `DownloadCallback` type).

Comment: In another class I have a `final DownloadCallback downloader` that assigned in constructor, You can use `final DownloadCallback downloader = publicFileDownloader;` to reproduce error

Comment: Your problem are that you are missing the generic part of the type. When you write `final DownloadCallback` you are actually saying `final DownloadCallback<dynamic>`. Try use `final downloader = publicFileDownloader;` or `final DownloadCallback<String> downloader = publicFileDownloader;`

Comment: Actually, you should also define your DownloadCallback as: ```typedef DownloadCallback<T> = Future<String> Function(
    String context,
    T fileIdentifier,
    );```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another case where trying to specify a type ends up making Dart more confused. The problem is that the following:

```
final DownloadCallback downloader = publicFileDownloader;
```

Actually means:

```
final DownloadCallback<dynamic> downloader = publicFileDownloader;
```

Therefore, what you should do is the following:

```
final DownloadCallback<String> downloader = publicFileDownloader;
```

Next problem is wrong use of generic when you are declaring your typedef. What you actually want are properly the following:

```
typedef DownloadCallback<T> = Future<StreamedResponse> Function(
  BuildContext context,
  T fileIdentifier,
);
```

So the complete code would be:

```
typedef DownloadCallback<T> = Future<StreamedResponse> Function(
  BuildContext context,
  T fileIdentifier,
);

Future<StreamedResponse> publicFileDownloader(
  BuildContext context,
  String url,
) {
  final request = Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
  return Client().send(request);
}

final DownloadCallback<String> downloader = publicFileDownloader;
```